# Deploying a bash-based server on Cloud Run: how to fix 502 Bad gateway error?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, webserver, google-cloud-run, netcat

I am trying to deploy a bash server on Cloud run in order to easily trigger gcloud commands with parameters that would be passed with the POST request to the service.
I take the inspiration mainly from [here](https://github.com/sethvargo/cloud-run-bash-example).

At the moment the bash server looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PORT=${PORT-8080}
echo "Listening on port $PORT..."


while true
do
    rm -f out
    mkfifo out
    trap "rm -f out" EXIT
    echo "Waiting.."
    cat out | nc -Nv -l 0.0.0.0 "${PORT}" > >( # parse the netcat output, to build the         answer redirected to the pipe "out".

    # A POST request is expected, so the request is read until the '}' ending the json payload.
    # while 
    read -d } PAYLOAD;
    # do

        # The contents of the payload are extracted by stripping the headers of the request
        # Then every entry of the json is exported :
        # export KEY=VALUE
        for s in $(echo $PAYLOAD} | \
                sed '/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s/^[^{]*//g' | \
                sed '/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s/[^}]*$//g' | \
                jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" ); 
        do     
            export $s; 
            echo $s;
        done
    
        echo "Running the gcloud command..."
        # gsutil mb -l $LOCATION gs://$BUCKET_NAME             
        printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted" "Content-length: 0" "Connection: Keep-    alive"  > out
    
    # done

    )
    continue
done
```

The Dockerfile for deployment looks like this:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:alpine

RUN apk add --upgrade jq netcat-openbsd coreutils \
    && apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash

COPY main.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["./main.sh"]
```

(Cloud SDK image with netcat-openbsd -server-, jq -JSON processing part-, and bash in addition)

With this quite simple setup I can deploy the service and it listens to incoming requests.
When receiving a POST request with a payload looking like

```
{"LOCATION": "MY_VALID_LOCATION", "BUCKET_NAME": "MY_VALID_BUCKET_NAME"}
```

the (here commented out) cloud SDK command runs correctly and creates a bucket with the specified name in the specified region, in the same project as the the Cloud Run service.

However, I receive a 502 error at the end of the process. (I'm expecting a 202 Accepted response).

The server seems to work correctly locally. However it seems that Cloud Run cannot receive the HTTP response.

How can I make sure the HTTP response is correctly transmitted back ?

Comment: I propose you something else. I contributed to [this open source project](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-firestore-backup) and it uses shell2http to serve bash as http server. Could be a nice shift for your project, isn't it?

Comment: This is indeed brilliant !
Thank you very much.

I'll leave the question open since this project was to get more familiar with both Bash and Cloud Run, and I still hope to understand what's happening here, but this is a very interesting outtake !

Merci infiniment !

Comment: I'm trying to deploy something similar but I'm unable to make it work with your code. Am I missing anything else? I've seen that in the project they use to .SH do you also have two?

Comment: Hi Anton, in the end I couldn't make it work in that way (still that 502 error), so I went with what @guillaume_blaquiere recommended, and had a bit more success. You can find the code there: https://github.com/cylldby/bash2run . 
Let me know if it works for you !

Comment: Could you please post it as a solution and not a comment? The process you took to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for insisting but, could you please post the solution as an answer and accept it? This action will increase visibility for future users looking for similar issues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @guillaumeblaquiere suggestion I managed to obtain a solution to what I was ultimately trying to do: running bash scripts on Cloud Run.

Two important points were to be able to : 1) be able to access the payload of the incoming HTTP request, 2) have access to google cloud SDK.

To do so, the trick was to build a Docker image based on not only on the Google SDK base image, but also on the shell2http one that deals with the server aspects.

The Dockerfile therefore looks like this:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:alpine

RUN apk add --upgrade jq
COPY --from=msoap/shell2http /app/shell2http /shell2http
COPY main.sh . 

ENTRYPOINT ["/shell2http","-cgi"]
CMD ["/","/main.sh"]
```

Thanks to the latter image, the HTTP processing is handled by a Go server and the incoming HTTP is piped into the stdin of the main.sh script.
The `-cgi` option also allows different environment variables to be set, for instance the $HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH variable that contains the length of the payload (therefore of the JSON containing the different parameters we want to extract and pass to further actions).

As such, with the following as the first line of our main.sh script:

```
read -n$HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH PAYLOAD;
```

the PAYLOAD is set with the incoming JSON payload.

Using `jq` it is then possible to do whatever we want.

All the code is gathered in this repository:
https://github.com/cylldby/bash2run

In addition, this solution is used in [this project](https://github.com/cylldby/workflow-trigger) in order to have a very simple solution to trigger a Google workflow from an eventarc trigger.

Big thanks again to @guillaume_blaquiere for the tip !

Comment: You might find this sample useful as well: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/eventarc-samples/tree/main/eventarc-workflows-integration/eventarc-auditlog-storage